# Accessing JavaScript variable across functions

Tags: javascript

I have a variable I'm setting to `true`, then later checking things in a couple different functions and re-setting it to false if a check fails.

Setting it here...

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    //Set enable_submit to true, then run checks to see if it should be reset to false
    var enable_submit = true;
}
```

Doing other checks.  Then, seeing if it's still true or not here...

```
function change_submit_button_state() {
    if (enable_submit == true) {
        $("button[type=submit]").prop("disabled", false);
    } else {
        $("button[type=submit]").prop("disabled", true);
    }
}
```

The problem is I'm getting a "ReferenceError: enable_submit is not defined" and the line referenced in the error is the `if (enable_submit == true) {` line from above.

Is there a way around this?

Comment: This was closed, but in my opinion the best answer to this would be to store the state with `data` on the button, and then just access that. It's availble everywhere, and avoids globals

Comment: @adeneo: Do you have a reference for your idea?  Not sure what "store the state with `data` on the button" means.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/5gg33hvw/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should just wrap the function within `document.ready` method.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   //Set enable_submit to true, then run checks to see if it should be reset to false
   var enable_submit = true;
   function change_submit_button_state() {
     if (enable_submit == true) {
        $("button[type=submit]").prop("disabled", false);
     } else {
        $("button[type=submit]").prop("disabled", true);
     }
   }
}
```

In your code `enable_submit` variable has a local **scope** .